# boost::thread yield different results on every run

Tags: c++, threadpool, boost-thread

I am trying to make use of boost::thread to perform "n" similar jobs. Of course, "n" in general could be exorbitantly high and so I want to restrict the number of simultaneously running threads to some small number m (say 8). I wrote something like the following, where I open 11 text files, four at a time using four threads.

I have a small class `parallel` (which upon invoking `run()` method would open an output file and write a line to it, taking in a int variable. The compilation goes smoothly and the program runs without any warning. The result however is not as expected. The files are created, but they are not always 11 in number. Does anyone know what's the mistake I am making?

Here's parallel.hpp:

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>

 #include <boost/thread.hpp>

 class parallel{
 public:
    int m_start;

    parallel()
    {  }

    // member function
    void run(int start=2);
};
```

The parallel.cpp implementation file is

```
#include "parallel.hpp"

void parallel::run(int start){

    m_start = start;

    std::cout << "I am " << m_start << "! Thread # " 
          << boost::this_thread::get_id()
          << " work started!" << std::endl;

    std::string fname("test-");
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << m_start << ".txt";

    fname.append(buffer.str());

    std::fstream output;
    output.open(fname.c_str(), std::ios::out);

    output << "Hi, I am " << m_start << std::endl;

    output.close();

    std::cout << "Thread # " 
          << boost::this_thread::get_id()
          << " work finished!" << std::endl;
}
```

And the main.cpp:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>

 #include <boost/thread.hpp>
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

 #include "parallel.hpp"

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

     std::cout << "main: startup!" << std::endl;
     std::cout << boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;

     parallel p;

     int populationSize(11), concurrency(3);

     // define concurrent thread group
     std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;

     // population one-by-one
     while(populationSize >= 0) {
         // concurrent threads
         for(int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++){
             // create a thread
             boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>
             thread(new boost::thread(&parallel::run, &p, populationSize--));
             threads.push_back(thread);
         }    
         // run the threads
         for(int i =0; i < concurrency; i++)
             threads[i]->join();

         threads.clear();
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single `parallel` object with a single `m_start` member variable, which all threads access without any synchronization.

**Update**

This race condition seems to be a consequence of a design problem. It is unclear what an object of type `parallel` is meant to represent.

- If it is meant to represent a thread, then one object should be allocated for each thread created. The program as posted has a single object and many threads.
- If it is meant to represent a group of threads, then it should not keep data that belongs to individual threads.

Comment: is that true? For the files created definitely have distinct indices.

Comment: I'm not sure what a file index is. Files have distinct names because the filesystem won't allow several files with identical names.

Comment: no-no... my code requires to suffix that m_start after the baseName of "test-"...

Comment: moreover, the does make the same files (filenames) again and again and the number of files created doesn't go up with each run... had that been the case with filesystem restriction

Comment: Indeed your code appends `m_start` to `test`. The problem is that the value of `m_start` is undefined in any one thread, because it is written over by all other threads.

Comment: I'm sorry I have a hard time understanding what are you talking about. Do you realize that you have many threads that read and write your most important variable `m_start` without synchronization? Do you realize that this is something that you should never ever allow to happen?

Comment: @Nikhil: just get rid of `m_start` - it serves no function for your thread function anyway - all you do is set it to the value of `start` (which as n.m. says screws up other thread's use of `m_start`).  Just use the `start` parameter in your thread function - each thread instance will get its own copy of that.

Comment: @n.m. and Michael Burr: Thanks a lot for your help. It helped a lot :)... I definitely understand threading better now :)... My main problem is this was a "toy" I developed to implement threading in my final project, where I will have to somehow pass an argument to a member function of a class (like start), which will re-assign a member (such as m_start) to perform further analysis... I don't know how to do it now :(... it seems I can not over-write class members in one thread this way :(

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: I think one common way to do this is to give each thread's data it's own own class/struct instance, and pass the  pointer for that instance to the thread. Just keep in mind that lifetime requirements of these objects often means that heap allocation is often the easiest way to make sure each thread gets their own copy for as long as the thread might need it (let the thread free the object when it's done). The key thing is that sharing a single instance of data among different threads won't work very well if each thread's data will be different.